# Unsubscribe from Feedburner email subscription

Tags: email, rss, feedburner

I subscribed to a Feedburner RSS feed with email as the delivery method:
[image]

After doing that I realized I subscribed with the wrong email address. How can I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the only practical option is to click the link to unsubscribe that comes with each e-mail message.

However, you might be able to contact the owner of the RSS feed and ask them to manually remove you. You'll want to do so from the same e-mail address you want removed or you're likely to be ignored.

Comment: I did not notice the `unsubscribe` link, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly, but isn't there an unsubscribe link in the emails they send to you? And if you put in an email address that doesn't exist, just subscribe with a new one - it's not like you're going to receive anything on the first address.

Comment: There was not an unsubscribe link and I did use a valid email address.

Comment: There should be a link. It looks like: `To stop receiving these emails, you may unsubscribe now` and it's at the bottom of the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confirmation link that is sent to the e-mail address you enter. If that is not clicked, which would seem to be the result of putting in an incorrect address, then the subscription is never activated. You can simple subscribe again with the correct address.

Comment: I did click it though.